# Do we need to repeat "no" to represent without for a list of items?

Tags: grammar

I want to say "This book comes without page numbers, footnotes and cover.".

But if I use "with no" instead of "without", should I repeat the word "no"?

> A: This book comes with no page numbers, footnotes, and cover.

or

> B: This book comes with no page numbers, no footnotes, and no cover.

Comment: I think you do not have to repeat "no" but I would change your conjunction from "and" to "or": *This book comes with no page numbers, footnotes, or cover.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it depends on your choice of conjunction at the end of the list. If you use **or**, then you don't need to repeat the negation:

> This book comes with no page numbers, footnotes, or cover.

…whereas if you use **and**, you *do* need to repeat the negation (as in your example B):

> This book comes with no page numbers, no footnotes, and no cover.

Here, the repeated use of the word *no* adds emphasis to the missing items.

Comment: "or" will make the sentence contain uncertain meaning whether there is a cover or not, right?

Comment: @HiggsBoson No, "cover" must be part of the list. If you want to make it so that the book could have a cover (like if you were presenting two possibilities for how the book comes), you could say, e.g. "This book comes with [either] no page numbers and no footnotes, or a cover."

Comment: So, in and case, there is no need to repeat the negation? It is only for adding emphasis. Right?

Comment: @Carlo_R. Right

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly correct and clear to say ***this book comes with no page numbers, footnotes or cover*** as mentioned in other answers. Note that no comma is required before the conjunction ***or***.

Comment: You’re a bit misleading about the serial comma business.  Careful writers and careful publications always use it. You should, too.

Comment: I'm afraid that that is contrary to what I was consistently taught and I apologise if it is considered misleading. I will not be using the comma.

Comment: @tchrist Some of the publications and style manuals [listed here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma#Style_guides_opposing_mandatory_use) might be considered "careful." Really, there is nothing approaching universal consensus about whether or not it's best to use the serial comma.